# Japanse Vertical text display issue on mobile

Tags: html, css, text

So I have this problem I am trying to solve..
I got some text in some table, and I would like it to be shown in vertical orientation when the user access the page from mobile, because it is a quite long text and would fit better being vertical.

Now this is my code:

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
ul.vert_text {
    text-orientation: upright;
    text-align: justify;    
    word-wrap: break-all;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  }
  }
</style>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>ダミーテキスト</td>
<td>ダミーテキスト</td>
<td>ダミーテキスト</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ダミーテキスト</td>
<td>
<ul class="vert_text">
        
     <li>ダミーテキストダミーテキスト</li>
     <li>ダミーテキストダミーテキスト</li>
     <li>ダミーテキストダミーテキストダミーテキストダミーテキスト</li><br>
     <li>ダミーテキスト</li>
        
</ul>
</td>
<td>
<ul class="vert_text">
        
     <li>ダミーテキスト</li>
     <li>ダミーテキストダミーテキストダミーテキスト</li>
     <li>ダミーテキストダミーテキスト</li>
        
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ダミーテキスト</td>
<td>
<ul class="vert_text">
        
     <li>ダミーテキスト</li>
     <li>ダミーテキストダミーテキスト</li>
     <li>ダミーテキストダミーテキストダミーテキストダミーテキスト</li>
        
</ul>
</td>
<td>
<ul class="vert_text">
        
     <li>ダミーテキストダミーテキスト</li>
     <li>ダミーテキスト</li>
     <li>ダミーテキストダミーテキスト</li>
     <li>ダミーテキストダミーテキストダミーテキスト</li>
        
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

When I try it on pc browser simulating the mobile screen, the text has no problem but when I try it with safari on the iphone, it does not display properly (it overflows out of the table and it does not display vertical, but from right to left)
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
-webkit-text-orientation: upright;
-webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;